# Proving isomorphism: $\Phi (z w) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (w)$ versus $\Phi (z^2) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> The case of: Prove or disprove that $U(8) \cong Z_4$

I understand that $U(8)=\{1,3,5,7\}$ a group under the operation multiplication mod8 and $Z_4 = \{0,1,2,3\}$ a group under the operation addition mod4.

Given the function $\Phi: U(8) \longrightarrow Z_4$, I chose the following bijection:
$$ 1 \longrightarrow 0 $$
$$ 3 \longrightarrow 1$$
$$ 5 \longrightarrow 2$$
$$ 7 \longrightarrow 3$$

I want now to show that the group operations are preserved. Given $a,b \in U(8)$, Let's check that $$\Phi(ab \space mod8)=[\Phi(a) +\Phi(b)] mod4$$
I did check with several values and it shows that the group operations are preserved.

I understood that to prove an isomorphism:

1. Prove that the group is homomorphic whereby the operation is preserved by showing that  => $\Phi (z \space \circ \space w) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (w)$
2. Prove $\Phi$ is one-to-one
3. Prove $\Phi$ is onto

I posted a question related to this earlier https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2230045?noredirect=1 But the response to this was to test with instead $\Phi (z^2) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (z)$

My take on this is that **if the function rule is not given and that the function is defined solely by a mapping of your choosing**, You are to pick the second property to test directly the isomorphism:  $\Phi (z^2) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (z)$. Is this correct?

Can you use $\Phi (z^2) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (z)$ if the function rule is given to you?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Didn't the answers on the question you linked to show you that these two groups are not isomorphic? And that your map does not preserve the group operations? Finding a $z$ such that $\Phi(z^2) \neq \Phi(z) \cdot \Phi(z)$ would prove that $\Phi$ is not a homomorphism. I don't understand what you asking about the "function rule."

Comment: My question here is about the decision making: when do you choose method 1? when do you choose method 2?

Comment: $\Phi (z \space \circ \space w) = \Phi (z)\cdot \Phi (w)$ this case includes the case where $z=w$, so if you want to test all of them, don't forget this case.

Comment: Method 1 is how you prove a function is an isomorphism. Method 2 is one of many ways of showing that a function is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Is $U(8)$ cyclic? Do isomorphisms preserve the property of being cyclic?

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input. I am still in the learning process. I would say that U(8) is not cyclic as there is no generator.

Comment: So using the theorem that "if G is a cyclic group of order n, then G is isomorphic to $Z_n$. But it is not an "if and only if" theorem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to show that "for some values" we have $\phi(z\cdot w) = \phi(z) + \phi(w)$...it must be true for ALL values of $z,w \in U_8$.

In this case, you have $\phi(3\cdot 3) = \phi(1) = 0$, whereas $\phi(3) + \phi(3) = 1 + 1 = 2 \neq 0$.

Indeed, every non-identity element of $U_8$ is of order $2$, which precludes it having a cyclic generator (which would have to be of order $4$), which settles the question (regardless of which bijection we attempt to find).

Comment: Another question: Is there a relation between the order of elements and the order of a group? I understood that the order of a group is the number of element in the group and that the order of an element is the smallest index by which this element is raised to yielding the identity. For example $Z_4$ has 2 elements of order 4, 1 of order 2, and the identity order 1.

Comment: Not a "strict" relation-although the order of an element always divides the order of a (finite) group, there may or may not be more you can say. One exception is cyclic groups, where the order of a generator *is* the order of the group. The same goes for cyclic subgroups generated by a single element: $|\langle g\rangle| = |g|$.